# How can I replace "Powered by Odoo" (footer) in outgoing emails, when I sent sale order in odoo?

Tags: odoo-11

Which template should I inherit and extend? Is it sale/data/mail_template_data.xml?

I've attached image of how the email looks like now.[Outgoing email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAeN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to odoo-addons and find and find

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.odoo.com">Odoo</a>
```

you will find email template and inherit it and make changes as you want.

Comment: I have found the template. It is with id="sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order". Though I\m having problems inheriting it. I've tried this way, but it's not working:                              <record id="sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order_custom" inherit_id="mail.sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order"><xpath expr="//field[@name='body_html']" position="replace"><field name="body_html">...Here the custom template....</field></xpath></record>

Comment: you can override like this


 <record id="sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order" model="email.template">
        <field name="body_html">new body</field>
    </record>